# SQL Server 2016 CLR Stored Procedure with nullable out parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, nullable, sqlclr

I have created a CLR stored procedure with the following method definition in C#:

```
public static void MyProcedure (SqlString path, SqlString fileName, out SqlBoolean? myValue)
```

But when I try to create it in SQL Server 2016:

```
create procedure [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
     @path nvarchar(max), 
     @fileName nvarchar(max), 
     @myValue bit output
with execute as caller 
as external name [MyAssembly].[StoredProcedures].[MyProcedure]
```

I get the following error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE for "MyProcedure" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@myValue" do not match.

Is there any possible way to create a CLR stored procedure which has a nullable out parameter? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the question mark off of the parameter type in the C# code. The `Sql*` types are already nullable.

To set any of the `Sql*` types to what will be `NULL` in T-SQL, use the static `Null` field  (e.g. `SqlBoolean.Null`).

To test any of the `Sql*` types to see if they are null, check the boolean `IsNull` property (e.g. `if (fileName.IsNull)`).

To learn more about working with SQLCLR in general, please take a look at the series that I am writing on that topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).

Comment: Then how do you go about setting its value to null? If I try `myValue = null` I receive a compile time error of "Cannot convert null to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean' because it is a non-nullable value type"

Comment: Glad you got it working :-). I updated again to add a little more info and a link to a series of articles I am working on that might be helpful.

Comment: I know this is a slightly different (but hopefully relevant) question, but if OP wanted to set his `myValue` parameter to the *default value* of `NULL`, is that possible to do directly in the method's signature such that it's an optional parameter? Seems like C# isn't happy with using `SqlBoolean.Null` in the method signature since it's not a compile-time constant (i.e. it results in error CS1736).

Comment: @J.D. Are you talking about setting this in the `[SqlFacet()]` so the generated SQL script contains `@myValue BIT = NULL OUTPUT`? If so, this is unfortunately not supported via VS / SSDT (please vote for my suggestion to support this: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5ab61883-7225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 ). Until it is fixed (and it never will be as Microsoft sadly doesn't like SQLCLR and probably wants to get rid of it) you need to update the proc definition manually in a post-deploy script. I don't use SSDT for publishing because of this and other deficiencies.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Nah, though I did see that was an issue as well. I more so mean literally the signature of the method definition in C#, e.g. in OP's case: `public static void MyProcedure (SqlString path, SqlString fileName, out SqlBoolean? myValue)`. If he instead wanted to do `public static void MyProcedure (SqlString path, SqlString fileName, out SqlBoolean myValue = SqlBoolean.Null)` then C# complains about `SqlBoolean.Null` not being a compile-time constant, and prevents the code from compiling.

Comment: @J.D. That's what I'm saying: parameter defaults aren't supported. You want to have an optional parameter. The only way to do that is to specify the default in the T-SQL wrapper object, and that can only happen by specifying something via `SqlFacet()` for that parameter, and that is not supported. SQL Server doesn't probe .NET method signatures to determine if default values are specified in order to determine if a parameter is optional or not during parsing. It can only go by the T-SQL definition. And that can be done manually, just not for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `VARBINARY(MAX)`, or `XML`.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Gotcha, I guess I misread the other posts thinking it was referring to something else, thanks! My use case is to debug my CLR method locally with a certain set of parameter values but didn't want to make those parameters required once it's compiled to a stored procedure on my SQL Server instance. 